# Wordpress: IF Statement Results and Using as Variable

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, if-statement

I have almost zero to PHP knowledge, but I need to make something workout. I have if statements resulting me to find the available ( either deal or current ) price of the products in a list.

```
<?php 
$currentPrice = get_field('incentive_current_price');
$oldPrice = get_field('incentive_old_price');

if ( ($currentPrice != null) && ($oldPrice != null))  {
    the_field('incentive_current_price');
}
elseif ( ($currentPrice == null) && ($oldPrice != null)) {
    the_field('incentive_old_price');
} 
elseif ( ($currentPrice != null) && ($oldPrice == null)) {
    the_field('incentive_current_price');
}
else {
}
?>
```

This works okay. I have also another field where I need to display lowest priced product from out of this list. What I use for this is:

```
$connected = new WP_Query( array(
'connected_type' => 'incentives_to_products',
'connected_items' => get_queried_object(),
'nopaging' => true,
'meta_key'      => 'incentive_old_price',
'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
'order'         => 'DESC') );
```

the problem is sometimes I have current_prices and this just ignores it orderby old_price. Is there a way to save my if statement as a variable and use in the meta_key part. Or any do you have other methods to achieve this?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple to save as a variable.

If the code you want to use it in is in scope, you can just create your variable inside the if statements.

Looks like `the_field()` echoes directly, so you would either have to find a corresponding function that returns rather than echoes, or use output buffering to save the result to a variable.

The latter:

```
if ( ($currentPrice != null) && ($oldPrice != null))  {
    the_field('incentive_current_price');
    ob_start();   
       the_field('incentive_current_price');
       $my_price = ob_get_contents;
     ob_end_clean();
}
elseif ( ($currentPrice == null) && ($oldPrice != null)) {
    ob_start();   
       the_field('incentive_old_price');
       $my_price = ob_get_contents;
     ob_end_clean();
} 
elseif ( ($currentPrice != null) && ($oldPrice == null)) {
    ob_start();   
       the_field('incentive_current_price');
       $my_price = ob_get_contents;
     ob_end_clean();
}
else {
$my_price = 'default_value';
}
```

If you need to use it out of scope, you could declare it as a global, and it will be available everywhere in your script.

```
global $my_price;
```

Then when you want to use it

```
global $my_price;
echo $my_price;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for clear answer. 
Yes, the_field() echoes directly, if I use get_field() it doesn't.